# Readmore doesn't work when I have an unorderlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I have an unordered list of paragraph text inside the container, the read more/readless  does not hide any text before the UL list

https://codepen.io/tickatop/pen/NZavXg

Almost made me run crazy

```
 <div class= "col2">
<p class="lead" height="50">>
<strong>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem cum quisquam praesentium incidunt, ad, placeat debitis voluptatum, quidem quo velit architecto eligendi </strong>voluptate officia soluta explicabo aliquam facilis illo temporibus sint eaque repudiandae quis ducimus! Placeat exercitationem ex voluptate ratione aut facere cupiditate sunt. Officiis veniam, inventore dolore. Soluta temporibus, veritatis labore optio enim consectetur ipsa?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti sequi non qui, quas, quod ad vel facilis consectetur sint, culpa eum. Maiores, maxime, quisquam. Assumenda error sapiente numquam quibusdam praesentium perspiciatis minima, architecto maiores ipsa, <ul>
<li>ndskdsmd</li>
<li>sdkdnskdskds</li>
<li>dskdnskdnskdsnk</li>
</ul>corporis, soluta dolor magnam vel id quis eveniet recusandae asperiores totam sit eligendi commodi. Nam nemo, dicta. Ut asperiores commodi sint debitis laborum harum facilis, dolore obcaecati vel adipisci dolorem modi quas eos deserunt quae sed explicabo magnam reiciendis dolores odit ex nulla a! Impedit nulla unde, hic, commodi explicabo omnis nisi sed, recusandae quam possimus, magnam qui. Ex non laborum libero tempore similique, id.
Perspiciatis provident accusamus esse possimus, eveniet corrupti exercitationem magni soluta consequuntur nobis! Sequi molestiae repellat optio quaerat tempora veritatis illum voluptatem pariatur reiciendis? Repudiandae fugiat dignissimos, dolore laborum laudantium tempora odit, quo, labore animi eos nesciunt. Dicta nam voluptatum eaque suscipit nihil accusamus consequuntur.  </p>
<button class="more more-lead">Read more...</button>

</div>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Yes, because you're nesting `ul` under `p` tag, which is an invalid HTML, so the browser will place the `ul` tag right after the `p` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, what can I do if I still want to use paragraphs, or would <br> work

Comment: For start, you need to wrap the whole thing inside a `div` and not nest `ul` inside `p` elements. Something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BgwwRr

Comment: I used a span now like this instead, but the font size doesn't match.    The font size is not like the rest of the screen, it is larger

Comment: @Alon Eitan your solution worked, but the text seems larger

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful or not, but it has the function you are hoping for so it is an alternative at least. It also works for any number of read-more sections on a single page.

Note that the read more button has the class `.more`, and an attribute `for` which links it to the element that it sets the height for.

Hope this helps

---

## Demo

```js
// Hide on load via jquery to avoid issues where JS is disabled
// Cycle through each more button
$(".more").each(function() {

  // Find ID and store element
  id = $(this).attr("for");
  elem = $("#" + id);

  // Set height from inline property
  elem.css("height", elem.attr("height")).css("overflow", "hidden");



});

// Add click event to more button
$(".more").click(function() {

  // Find ID and store element
  id = $(this).attr("for");
  elem = $("#" + id);

  // Toggle expanded class
  // Could check for inline property being auto / set and adjust if you want to avoid an !important CSS rule
  elem.toggleClass("expanded");

  // Toggle text of buttons
  if ($(this).text() == "Read more...") {
    $(this).text("Read less...");

  } else {
    $(this).text("Read more...");
  }

})
```

```css
.expanded {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col2">
  <div id="lead" height="50">

    <p>
      <strong>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem cum quisquam praesentium incidunt, ad, placeat debitis voluptatum, quidem quo velit architecto eligendi </strong>voluptate officia soluta explicabo aliquam facilis illo temporibus
      sint eaque repudiandae quis ducimus! Placeat exercitationem ex voluptate ratione aut facere cupiditate sunt. Officiis veniam, inventore dolore. Soluta temporibus, veritatis labore optio enim consectetur ipsa? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Corrupti sequi non qui, quas, quod ad vel facilis consectetur sint, culpa eum. Maiores, maxime, quisquam. Assumenda error sapiente numquam quibusdam praesentium perspiciatis minima, architecto maiores ipsa,
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>ndskdsmd</li>
      <li>sdkdnskdskds</li>
      <li>dskdnskdnskdsnk</li>
    </ul>

    <p>corporis, soluta dolor magnam vel id quis eveniet recusandae asperiores totam sit eligendi commodi. Nam nemo, dicta. Ut asperiores commodi sint debitis laborum harum facilis, dolore obcaecati vel adipisci dolorem modi quas eos deserunt quae sed explicabo
      magnam reiciendis dolores odit ex nulla a! Impedit nulla unde, hic, commodi explicabo omnis nisi sed, recusandae quam possimus, magnam qui. Ex non laborum libero tempore similique, id. Perspiciatis provident accusamus esse possimus, eveniet corrupti
      exercitationem magni soluta consequuntur nobis! Sequi molestiae repellat optio quaerat tempora veritatis illum voluptatem pariatur reiciendis? Repudiandae fugiat dignissimos, dolore laborum laudantium tempora odit, quo, labore animi eos nesciunt.
      Dicta nam voluptatum eaque suscipit nihil accusamus consequuntur. </p>
  </div>
  <button class="more" for="lead">Read more...</button>

</div>

<div class="col2">
  <div id="second" height="50">

    <p>
      <strong>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem cum quisquam praesentium incidunt, ad, placeat debitis voluptatum, quidem quo velit architecto eligendi </strong>voluptate officia soluta explicabo aliquam facilis illo temporibus
      sint eaque repudiandae quis ducimus! Placeat exercitationem ex voluptate ratione aut facere cupiditate sunt. Officiis veniam, inventore dolore. Soluta temporibus, veritatis labore optio enim consectetur ipsa? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Corrupti sequi non qui, quas, quod ad vel facilis consectetur sint, culpa eum. Maiores, maxime, quisquam. Assumenda error sapiente numquam quibusdam praesentium perspiciatis minima, architecto maiores ipsa,
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>ndskdsmd</li>
      <li>sdkdnskdskds</li>
      <li>dskdnskdnskdsnk</li>
    </ul>

    <p>corporis, soluta dolor magnam vel id quis eveniet recusandae asperiores totam sit eligendi commodi. Nam nemo, dicta. Ut asperiores commodi sint debitis laborum harum facilis, dolore obcaecati vel adipisci dolorem modi quas eos deserunt quae sed explicabo
      magnam reiciendis dolores odit ex nulla a! Impedit nulla unde, hic, commodi explicabo omnis nisi sed, recusandae quam possimus, magnam qui. Ex non laborum libero tempore similique, id. Perspiciatis provident accusamus esse possimus, eveniet corrupti
      exercitationem magni soluta consequuntur nobis! Sequi molestiae repellat optio quaerat tempora veritatis illum voluptatem pariatur reiciendis? Repudiandae fugiat dignissimos, dolore laborum laudantium tempora odit, quo, labore animi eos nesciunt.
      Dicta nam voluptatum eaque suscipit nihil accusamus consequuntur. </p>
  </div>
  <button class="more" for="second">Read more...</button>

</div>
```